# Unable to locate credentials inside fargate container, using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to create a container that splits files and then uploads them to S3 container. The process works as intended, but when trying to send the file to S3 it fails with the error `Unable to locate credentials inside fargate container`.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /tmp/splitter

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir requests boto3

RUN wget -O /tmp/init.sh (WHATEVER) \
    && chmod +x /tmp/init.sh

CMD /tmp/init.sh
```

I have my role set up like the ecsTaskExecutionRole that appears [in Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ecsTaskExecutionRole` is not for your container to access S3. It is for ECS itself to be able to, e.g. pull your docker image from ECR.

For your application permissions in the container, you need a [task role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), not the task execution role. It can be confusing because both are named similarly and both have same trust policy.

The task role can be specified along task execution role:

[image]

The roles can also be set at task definition level:

[image]

Comment: So then I have to get that role and then pass it through ecs-params file when creating the task? I mean inside `task_role_arn`.

Comment: @MarcosPérezFontecha When you create your task, there is option to provide task role and task execution role as on the screenshot (answer updated).

Comment: I finally got it to work thank to your answer. I've finally understood the difference between the Task Execution Role and the actual Task Role. Thank you so much for your help, have a nice day!

Comment: @MarcosPérezFontecha No problem. Glad it worked out :-)