Trying to access Dynamo from AWS ECS - botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
I have a Python application using boto3, and trying to access a dynamo table. When trying this as a local container, it works perfectly.
I then set up an IAM role for me ECS task to use. I can see in the console that the role is correctly assigned to the task, under the Task Execution Role.
This is the trust policy in IAM:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

And this is the attached policy to the role:
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:159*****:table/*",
            "Sid": "TableOperations"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:159*****:table/*/index/*",
            "Sid": "ScanAndQuery"
        },
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "List"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}

When deploying my application to ECS, I get the following error:
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
I've even tried to assume the role through the cli, and use those credentials in my local docker container - and that doesn't work either. So there's something in the role itself, I assume?
So I'm a bit stumped as to what the issue might be.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992423/unable-to-locate-credentials-inside-fargate-container-using-boto3 It should be task role and not task execution role

Wow ok that's a bit confusing. Thank you so much! You saved me more headache
